# Возможно ли реализация системы моддинга apk-игры на android с помощью java?

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, apk

**Чисто теоретический вопрос, я не требую кода.** (И у меня нет кода :D)

Сейчас я делаю игру на Unity (C#) с системой моддинга. Моя игра при запуске считывает папку mods и ищет необходимые файлы. Найдя .dll файл, игра загружает с него необходимые классы и использует их. Но вот незадача! .dll, как я выяснил, поддерживаются только на ПК, если не только на Windows.

Теперь я задумываюсь... А что если сделать игру на Java, ведь в Android apk-файлы хотя бы чуть-чуть пользуются встроенной в ОС java-виртуальной машиной. Получается, что возможно .jar файлы можно прочесть рефлексией из apk-файла?

**В общем.** Я хочу сделать игру на Java под Android и собрать её в .apk-файл. В этой игре будет использоваться IO для поиска модов. Если мод нашёлся, то рефлексия берёт из него классы и использует. А пишутся моды примерно так: человек берёт исходный код моей игры с открытого GitHub репозитория и пишет нужный для модификации код (пишет новые классы). Собирает свой код (только свои новые классы) в один jar-файл (типа "библиотека классов" без метода main) и всё, мод готов. **Возможно ли это?** Если нет, то какие альтернативы есть? Идею интерпретируемого языка и интерпретатора я рассматривать не хочу, так как знаю что это и как работает.

Comment: _человек берёт исходный код моей игры с открытого GitHub репозитория и пишет_... троянца, который через вашу игру чего-нибудь натворит. Загружать сторонний код в приложение в принципе нежелательно, лучше ограничиться ресурсными модами. Интерпретатор, кстати, предпочтительнее для выполнения кода - он даёт полный контроль над происходящим. Но если вас не пугают последствия, то в андроиде тоже можно загружать нативные библиотеки (под капотом ядро линукса, поэтому `.so` вместо `.dll`), правда внешние, не упакованные в сам APK может быть проблематично загрузить.

Comment: @woesss Я вдохновился песочницами Minecraft и Terraria. Например в Minecraft создают свои модификации для различных неофициальных загрузчиков модов типа Forge или Fabric. В итоги получается jar-файл. Но в Minecraft по сути никто не проверяет модификации. Вообще можно было бы сделать официальную библиотеку модов, где все моды проверяю я или какие-нибудь модераторы. Сделать подобное не сложно, я думаю.

Comment: Ну предупреждён - вооружён. Да, в Андроиде можно загружать внешний код: https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader. Но в Андроиде нет JRE, там свой "велосипед" ART, со своим набором библиотек и со своим байт-кодом. Поэтому для андроида нужно java-классы дополнительно конвертировать в DEX, и не всё из JDK можно использовать. Загружать можно непосредственно DEX, а также JAR, ZIP и APK с DEX внутри. То есть если в JAR положить и классы и DEX, то получится универсальный модуль для ПК и Андроида.

Comment: Но универсальное приложение для ПК и Андроида на Java сделать нельзя. Можно лишь частично переиспользовать код.